# Symfony 4.x ROLE_USER error when rendering a form with $form->createView()

Tags: symfony-4.2

I'm creating a blog with Symfony 4 and generate forms with :

> php bin/console make:form

when I try to render it like this :

```
    /**
    *   Require ROLE_USER for only this controller method.
    *   @Route("/create", name="post.create")
    *   @return Response
    */
    public function create(): Response
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(CreatePostType::class, $post);

        return new Response($this->twig->render('pages/create.html.twig'), [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

I get this error

> Could not convert database value "'ROLE_USER'" to Doctrine Type json

for this line

> 'form' => $form->createView()

Here is my getRoles :

```
    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }
```

and my security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
```

I'm searching for 3 days and restarted my project in a 2nd directory without the security management, I don't understand were it's from and how to solve it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the roles property is not stored as json-type in your database.  Can you check the type of the roles field in the database?

As a sidenote, you can rewrite the response to:

```
return $this->render('pages/create.html.twig', [
  'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
```